# What type to use to save a set of values in user control's state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, user-controls

I have a base class for some kind of user controls, and in that base class and in its inherited classes I want to store some properties. I use

```
protected override object SaveControlState()
protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
```

methods to save or load my custom values. Since I can work only with 1 parameter of type object, I have to use some kind of list if I want to work with more than 1 variable.

I tried to do it with

```
[Serializable]
public class ControlSate : Dictionary<string, object>, ISerializable
{   
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, 
      StreamingContext context)
    {
    }

    public ControlSate(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {    
    }

    public ControlSate()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

but it didn't work, and looking for a solution I have read that Dictionary is not serializable.

So, my question *is what type should I use to work with a set of values in user control's state?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `LoadControlState` does pass you an `Object` it is possible for that `Object` to be an `Object[]`.  In other words you are more than welcome to store an array of `Objects` in ControlState.  I also believe that ControlState is optimized to work with the [`System.Web.UI.Pair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx) type so you can create trees of objects in ControlState if you wish.

Please read [this excellent article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/16/gain-control-of-your-control-state.aspx) for the best way of storing multiple values in ControlState.

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how many items will be in the collection, and as far as I know arrays in c# has to be declared with precise length

Comment: Correct - but you *can* store a List<T> in the Object array and push that into ControlState.

Answer (score 0):

For storing complex state there is the IStateManager interface.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. If you look at the generic Dictionary<T,U> in Reflector, it has a [Serializable] attribute. I noticed that you have a Dictionary<string,object>, 
so U = 'object' here.
What is the real type of 'U'?. 
If you are using a complex type for 'U' then that needs to be marked [Serializable] as well. You may also need to explicitly mark each field and /or property as [Serializable] as well.
If this doesn't work, it might be worthwhile trying to use a List<KeyValuePair<T,U>>

Answer (score 0):

I'd question the srializable attribute on a property as according to the compiler:

Attribute 'Serializable' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, struct, enum, delegate' declarations.